# ffmpeg: capture two screens simultaneously, save as two separate files

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

Is this possible? Here is my working *single file* solution. How can I modify it to save two separate files instead?

```
ffmpeg \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1440x900 -i 1 \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1440x900 -i 2 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 \
  -filter_complex \
    "nullsrc=size=2880x900 [background]; \
    [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1440x900 [left]; \
    [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1440x900 [right]; \
    [background][left] overlay=shortest=1 [background+left]; \
    [background+left][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=1440 [left+right]" \
  -map [left+right] out.mov
```

I've tried removing the filter complex. I've tried adding two output files. I've tried various combinations of mapping. The following is the closest I've gotten to making it work. It creates two files, but both contain only the second stream (-i 2).

```
ffmpeg \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1440x900 -i 1 \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1440x900 -i 2 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 out1.mov \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 out2.mov
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to run only _one_ ffmpeg instance? The simplest solution seems to be two concurrent processes and limit cpu usage on each with the -threads options.

Comment: @hdezela Two instances would be fine. But could you show me how to do that? I just tried two semicolon separated ffmpeg commands but it just ran one right after the other.

Comment: You can use nohup <COMMAND1> & nohup <COMMAND2> &, ffmpeg likes to output to screen and err so you have to detach it and send it to background. (the & after cmd2 is not a typo, it's there to send cmd2 to the background).

Comment: @hdezela I gave it a try, see my update to the question. Can you tell what I'd doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `map` option:

```
ffmpeg \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1440x900 -i 1 \
-f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -s 1440x900 -i 2 \
-map 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 out1.mov \
-map 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -preset ultrafast -b:v 5000k -t 15 out2.mov
```